# Import component condinally, reactjs with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    

let SomeComp;
if (process.env.REACT_APP_V === '1') {
  SomeComp = import('../section/SomeComp');
}

Class App

...

render() {
  return {
    {this.state.version === '1' && <SomeComp />}
  }
}
```

I want to import the `SomeComp` component conditionally.

Is this the correct way?

The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components)
```

If I do a normal

```
import SomeComp from '../section/SomeComp';
```

it works. So it's no issue with the export from `SomeComp`

Any ideas?

Comment: I would avoid this if you can. Can't you pass in the component to the component? In any case, the problem here is that dynamic `import()` is async (it returns a promise) so you cannot render it until it's loaded.

Comment: I see. It's a css issue so I can condionally import the css file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    const SomeComp = React.lazy(() => import('./SomeComp'));

    Class App
    render() {
      return {
        <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
         {this.state.version === '1' && <SomeComp />}
        </Suspense>
      }

    }
```

You will run into issues if you are using a back end server. The suspense should wrap the relevant code that is loaded on demand. You might also want to look into this neat little `npm` [here (react loadable)](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable)

Comment: I get "Add a <Suspense fallback=...> component higher in the tree to provide a loading indicator or placeholder to display."

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ternary statement, like an if/else statement. So in this case if version = 1, the component will render:

```
{(this.state.version === '1') ? <SomeComp />
: null
}
```

Comment: Why use ternary over logical operator? what is the benefit of returning null here?

Comment: @Kleo If you don't want the component to render at all if the requirement is not met you can return an empty div or null.

Comment: First of all, returning an empty div is bad practice. No reason to overload the DOM with an empty div. Second of all, unless you will be doing something with null, you should be using && operator. Logical over ternary always if what you are trying to achieve is simply render or not render.